# Convergence & absolute convergence of an infinite series

Tags: sequences-and-series

How can i find all possible values for $a > 0$ which make the series absolute convergent?

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{5^n}{(4^n+a^n)}$$

Comment: Since the numerator has a $5^n$, we don't have to worry about that $4^n$ in the denominator. Now think in line of geometric series that has to be convergent

Comment: Have you tried the Root Test for convergence?

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales I just did and it worked :) thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\textbf{Hint}$: Use the root test and the fact that

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \sqrt[n]{a^n+b^n} = \max(a,b)$$

Answer (score 0):

Well it is clear that for $a \leq 5$ the terms don't go to $0$ so the sum can't converge.

On the other hand, for $a > 5$, the ratio test gives you that the quotient of the terms tends to $|5/a| < 1$ so it's convergent.

Comment: Don't you mean a > 5?

Comment: @martycohen fixed it, thanks